# Why is my network bridge not working in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, networking, bridge

I can set up a network bridge in Windows XP and Windows Server 2003 on this machine without any troubles. But when I try the following under Windows 7

- Select two local network connection,
- Click right mouse button,
- Select bridge network

It gives me the humiliating message:

> To create a Network Bridge, you must
>   select at least two LAN or High-Speed
>   Internet connections that are not
>   being used by Internet Connection.

Why isn't this working on Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the Internet Connection Sharing feature enabled on one of these ? Having it enabled will prevent the bridge from being set up.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please take some time to familiriaze yourself with the FAQ and how the site works as it is not a tradisional forum. For example. This should have been a comment rather then an answers. Answers are specific to solving problems and not for prompting for more information.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the answer to be more clear. It was implicit that the ICS feature is likely causing the problem, and that the solution is to disable it.

Comment: @Diago- I don't think you can post comments with a rep of 11.

Comment: @kmarsh. So why don't the rest of the community help him along by up-voting him. He only needs 50 rep to comment?